# RecyclerView Two Types item height wrap content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, row-height, expandablerecyclerview

I use two `ViewType`s in my `adapter` to show different layouts:

```
        case 0:
            return new Holder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.faq_item, parent, false));
        case 2:
            return new HolderAnswer(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.faq_item_answer, parent, false));
        default:
            return null;
    }
```

By default each second `layout` has invisible(`GONE`) `TextView` which turns `Visible` on first item click

If I set first item  fixed `height` it works fine, but item can contain long texts sometimes that won't be seen:

```
<ConstraintLayout
layout_height="@dimen/..."
...>
....
</ConstraintLayout>
```

If I change `height` to `wrap_content` I can watch unexpected behavior: First and second elements has `height` equals `screen height`, but after few swipes to the end and to the beginning of the list the height fits to expected measures.

My guess, that it is because of using two view types or wrong alignments. Tried both true/false for `setHasFixedSize()`Here are layouts:

question.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container_question"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#CCEFF5">

<View
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="3dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="#ff008ca5"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/question"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/question" />

<com.hastee.pay.ui.view.Text
    android:id="@+id/question"
    style="@style/black_regular_15"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:infont="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/plus"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/plus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/question"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/question"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus_small" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

answer.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#CCEFF5">
<com.hastee.pay.ui.view.Text
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    style="@style/black_regular_13"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:alpha="0.7" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:background="@color/divider" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by simply switching from `ConstraintLayout` to `RelativeLayout`. Looks like incorrect work of the first one with complex lists.